# Help! Startup configuration error. initramfs-tools RESUME=UUUID=(uid swap)

Tags: 20.04, swap, initramfs, uuid

I updated my system (I use Ubuntu 20.04) through the command line; as always and it gave me the error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
    Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
    Creando árbol de dependencias       
    Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
    Calculando la actualización... Hecho
    Los siguientes paquetes se han retenido:
      linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
      linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
    Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
      adwaita-icon-theme desktop-file-utils gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
      intel-microcode libatk-adaptor libatk-bridge2.0-0 libjpeg-turbo8
      libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg-turbo8-dev libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
      libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libproxy1v5 libproxy1v5:i386
      libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libsqlite3-0
      libsqlite3-0:i386 linux-libc-dev orca pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
      pulseaudio-utils
    24 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 3 no actualizados.
    Se necesita descargar 11,0 MB de archivos.
    Se utilizarán 926 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
    ¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s

    Procesando disparadores para hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
    Procesando disparadores para gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.2-1~fakesync1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
    Procesando disparadores para systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2) ...
    Procesando disparadores para mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
    Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
    I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
    I: (UUID=8a0a831f-e617-4242-b58c-e177b94f20c7)
    I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Where can I find this configuration so I can fix it?:

Comment: It's not an error message, `I` stands for "Information". Isn't `/dev/sda5` your swap-partition? You can check with `swapon` where your swap is located. You don't need to anything if `/dev/sda5` is your swap-partition.

Comment: sorry, i dont understanding

Comment: I have the same messages everytime initramfs is updated during `apt upgrade`, it is not an error, it is an information. Please issue the command `swapon` to see where your swap is located, I'd guess `/dev/sda5` is your swap partition. If that is the case, you don't need to take any action about this.